# Is there anyway to access only the value of a dictionary in a child?

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase database for Swift, is there a way to access the value (as a string) from the dictionary. Each child has a key:value pair.  For example:

```
users
|-- Bob
    |-- Bob@gmail.com: "BOBBBBY"
```

Is there a way to access `"BOBBBBY"` as a string?
I am new to Swift so any help is appreciated.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense! Can you please add more info!?

Comment: Did you even check the official Firebase documentation or the [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)?

Comment: @DávidPásztor sorry about the confusion.  Yes I have read them.  Everytime I use child.value it will return the data as a dictionary not a string.  I would like just "BOBBY" as a string

Comment: @Siyavash there

Comment: Have a look at here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: @Siyavash I know what a dictionary is.  I want to retrieve the data from Firebase.  I guess i am not explaining well, thank you anyways.

Comment: @MichaelR. The easiest way to address the confusion is by sharing the [minimal possible code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Example from Firebase Database Docs

Taken directly from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    // Get user value
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? "" // <<< this line
    let user = User.init(username: username)

    // ...
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

## Updated for You

If you need multiple fields under the user:

```
ref.child("users").child("Bob").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
    let emailValue = value?["Bob@gmail.com"] as? String ?? ""
    // do more...
}
```

...or if you only need one value:

```
ref.child("users").child("Bob").child("Bob@gmail.com").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if let value = snapshot.value as? String {
        // use the value...
    }
}
```